# Resizing Picture

Tags: sidebar, images

I'm new to WP and am not sure how to re-size a picture.

I want to scale down the pic of the guy on this page:
http://www.millermusiclessons.com/

If you view the page source and find the source of the picture, it already has height and width attributes assigned to it. When I edit these attributes in Notepad++ and re-upload them to my server the page still looks the same (yes I am clearing my cache) How can I change these attributes? Any edits I make to to "index.php" never show up, but edits to "style.php" seem to always work.

Thanks

Comment: if your theme has a home.php or page.php you'd want to modify this not index.php. See theme hierarchy http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#sidebar_img img {
    width: 250px !important;
    height: auto;
}

#sidebar_img {
    text-align: center;
}
```

use this css.. change 250px with whatever you want.

Comment: thanks, that made it smaller. How can I center it now, though?

Comment: i added #sidebar_img change.. replace that width:300px definition with this one

Answer (score 1):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size has all you need to know.  If you're code/design impaired try: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-thumbnail-editor/screenshots/

Answer (score 1):

You should use WordPress's feature called [Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails). Read more about it, it should do it.

Comment: If you use Firebug and go to the site linked to, you should notice that the image is placed in the text widget: div .textwidget

Answer (score 0):

You can change them using css, but that isn't good practice since the server still loads the full size image. It appears this image is placed using the text-widget. You should be able to go to Appearance>Widgets and change the image dimensions to match the size of the actual image you uploaded. Be sure you have the correct URL for the newly uploaded image.

Comment: I went there and it lists all my widgets, but I don't see a way to change the image size.

Comment: never mind i added this and it works great! thanks             display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend using something like this (most themes already include it by default) to resize your images on the fly...

http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/

It's fairly easy to setup and use, and includes a ton of documentation.

Comment: TimThumb is basically out of date with WordPress' current thumbnail options.

Comment: I think you're thinking of the original timthumb... this is the revised version which has been optimized for WordPress by a different author.